# How can I limit my sql select to return only one row for max(date), and not multiple rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select only one id, which has the latest date column, but this sql query returns multiple rows. How can I select only the latest? MAX() doesn't seem to work

```
select ra.sourceid as partner1, max(ra.date) from ra_table ra join rap_table rap on parentid=ra.sourceid
where (ra.type = 'Normal' and (ra.name IS NOT NULL or ra.parent IS NOT NULL) and rap.createdate > ra.createdate)
group by ra.sourceid
;
```

Comment: some sample data, and ddl would be very helpful in getting you an accurate answer. Otherwise we are all just sort of guessing on what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Oracle 12c or later:

```
select ra.sourceid as partner1, 
    ra.date
from ra_table ra 
join rap_table rap
    on parentid=ra.sourceid
where (ra.type = 'Normal' 
    and (ra.name IS NOT NULL or ra.parent IS NOT NULL) 
    and rap.createdate > ra.createdate)
order by ra.date desc
fetch first row only;
```

On Oracle prior to 12c:

```
select *
from (
    select ra.sourceid as partner1, 
        ra.date
    from ra_table ra 
    join rap_table rap
        on parentid=ra.sourceid
    where (ra.type = 'Normal' 
        and (ra.name IS NOT NULL or ra.parent IS NOT NULL) 
        and rap.createdate > ra.createdate)
    order by ra.date desc
    )
where rownum = 1
```

Both queries here will return the id and date for the most recent date value among the results.  There's no need to aggregate since we're determining what to return with the sort and we only want the one row.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will be correct in your case but `SELECT FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` at the end can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MIN( sourceid ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ra.date DESC )` to get the lowest `sourceid` for the highest `date` value:

```
SELECT MIN( ra.sourceid ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ra.date DESC ) as partner1,
       max(ra.date)
from   ra_table ra
       join rap_table rap
       on parentid=ra.sourceid
where  ra.type = 'Normal'
and    (ra.name IS NOT NULL or ra.parent IS NOT NULL)
and    rap.createdate > ra.createdate;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use top 1 in your query with descending order:

```
select Top 1 ra.sourceid as partner1, max(ra.date) from ra_table ra join rap_table rap on parentid=ra.sourceid
where (ra.type = 'Normal' and (ra.name IS NOT NULL or ra.parent IS NOT NULL) and rap.createdate > ra.createdate)
group by ra.sourceid order by max(ra.date) desc
```

Comment: `TOP` is not a keyword in Oracle.

Comment: sorry, you can add in where clause (rownum = 1) and remove top 1

Answer (score -1):

MAX() is a group by function, as such if you ask for more than one column it will give you the max unique combination. As you're using an ID column in your query you are getting uniques always (defeats the purpose of a max).

You should tweak your query a bit:

```
select TOP 1 ra.sourceid as partner1 FROM ra_table ra 
WHERE ra.date = (SELECT  max(ra.date) 
from 
    ra_table ra 
    join rap_table rap on parentid=ra.sourceid
where 
    (ra.type = 'Normal' and (ra.name IS NOT NULL or ra.parent IS NOT NULL) and rap.createdate > ra.createdate)
group by ra.sourceid)
```

Comment: `TOP 1` is not valid Oracle syntax.